# Is this infinite sum convergent?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Given any $0<a<1$, is the sum

$$\displaystyle\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} xa^x$$

convergent? (where, the variable $x$ runs over all positive real numbers!)

I mean, does this sum have a meaning, or can it be given a meaning, or is it meaningless in any case?

In the particular case, note that the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} na^n$ is convergent for any fixed $0<a<1$.

Comment: Can a sigma run over all possible real numbers? The closest thing to a real sigma I can think of is integration.

Comment: How do you define a sum over uncountably many real numbers in the first place?

Comment: One definition, for $f(x) \ge 0$ is $\sum_x f(x) = \sup_{A \subset [0,\infty), A \text{ finite}} \sum_{x \in A} f(x)$. With this definition, the above sum will be infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following Lemma answers to your question:

**Lemma:** Let $A \subset (0, \infty)$ be an uncountable set. Then, for each $M>0$ there exists pairwise distinct $x_1,...,x_n \in A$ such that 
$$x_1+..+x_n >M$$

This shows that any uncountable "sum" of positive numbers is divergent.

**Proof of Lemma** Consider $A \cap (\frac{1}{m}, \infty)$. If all these sets would be finite, then 
$$A=\cup _m A \cap (\frac{1}{m}, \infty) $$
is a countable union of finite sets, which contradicts the uncountability of $A$.

This shows that there exists some positive integer $m$ such that $A$ contains infinitely many elements greater than $\frac{1}{m}$.

The Lemma follows immediately from this.

Answer (score 0):

For any $n \in \Bbb N$, there are at least $n$ values $x \in [0,\infty)$ such $xa^x > a^{1} = a$.  Thus, I would claim that your sum is necessarily greater than $n \cdot a$ for any $n$.  Thus, your sum necessarily diverges to infinity.